# Could anyone help me understand what this function means?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to select **three** out of the ten classes of the cifar10, and I was provided with this code by my teacher. I don't get what it means, and I keep getting errors later on in the code that i suspect come from here.
Specifically, what does the tf.where function do?
The shapes for all the variables are the same, specifically

```
 def load_cifar10(num_classes=3):
 
    (x_train_all, y_train_all), (x_test_all, y_test_all) = cifar10.load_data()

    fil_train = tf.where(y_train_all[:, 0] < 3)[:, 0]
    fil_test = tf.where(y_test_all[:, 0] < 3)[:, 0]

    y_train = y_train_all[fil_train]
    y_test = y_test_all[fil_test]

    x_train = x_train_all[fil_train]
    x_test = x_test_all[fil_test]

    return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)
```

Indeed, the shapes are weird:

```
print(x_test.shape)
print(x_test_all.shape)
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_train_all.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
print(y_test_all.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_train_all.shape)
```

gives the result:

```
(10000, 32, 32, 3, 1)
(10000, 32, 32, 3)
(50000, 32, 32, 3, 1)
(50000, 32, 32, 3)
(10000, 10)
(10000, 1)
(50000, 10)
(50000, 1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing `tf` is a pandas dataframe. But it's really not possible to make a guess here. The function seems to use global variables `tf` and `cifar10` that are not passed in as arguments, and there is no docstring, type annotation, comments or meaningful variable names. Maybe it's written by someone who is not familiar with good programming practices.

Comment: @HåkenLid the tag  `tensorflow` is in the question, `tf` is a common way of importing tensorflow in a short way. `cifar10` is a module from the `tensorflow_dataset` library. `tf.where` is an equivalent of `numpy.where` for tensorflow's Tensors.

Answer (score 0):

As per convention, `tensorflow` module is imported as `tf`. To execute the code you should import it as such.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

The [documentation  of the function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) states `tf.where` as a function that "Returns the indices of non-zero elements, or multiplexes x and y."

Multiple examples are given in the site.